# LazyInitializationException even though @Transactional is used

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Currently I am  getting the following exception:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
> a collection of role: com.example.model.Link.subLinks, could not
> initialize proxy - no Session

I googled and I found another solution for this exception but I would like to know why @Transactional in my case is not working. I am sure that I am doing something wrong. What am I doing wrong?

**The weird part is that I used @Transactional already somewhere else in this project and there it works.**

Thank you in advance for any tips.

**My Link class:**
The entity Link contains a collection of SubLink.

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Link {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    
    @NotEmpty
    private String title;
    
    @NotEmpty
    private String description;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "link")
    private Collection<SubLink> subLinks;
}
```

**My SubLink class:**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class SubLink {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    
    @NotEmpty
    private String type;
    
    @NotEmpty
    @URL
    private String url;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "link_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Link link;
}
```

**My LinkServiceImpl class:**

```
    @Service
    public class LinkServiceImpl implements LinkService {
        @Autowired
        public LinkRepository linkRepository;
        
        @Override
        @Transactional
        public Link findById(long id) {
            return linkRepository.findById(id);
        }
    }
```

**In my controller class there is the method showLink():**

```
    @GetMapping("/link/{linkId}")
    public String showLink(@PathVariable(value = "linkId") long linkId, Model model) {
        Link link = linkService.findById(linkId);

        
        Collection<SubLink> subLinkCollection = link.getSubLinks(); //Error
        model.addAttribute("subLinkCollection", subLinkCollection);
        return "link";
    }
```

Comment: Would you please provide the Link Entity Structure? Which will be helpful in understanding.

Comment: Hi @SebinThomas , I added the Link class. Thanks!

Comment: By default fetchType is already EAGER if you have not mentioned LAZY. Is your SubLink class contains any Lazy properties?

Comment: I added the SubLink class too. But to answer your question: I think not

Comment: In your Repository you have used Query or QueryMethod? If Query, have you tried @Aman suggested? And if find by Id what is the reason for using the Query method? you could have used the default method provided by JpaRepository ie, findById. Just checking with you.

Comment: Neither nor. Im not using @Query here. I am using '@Transactional' only. I would like to know why '@Transactional' is not working in my example. The reason why I am not using the default method is that it returns Optional<Link> but I want just a Link.

Comment: Have you tried excluding subLinks in @EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "subLinks"). Sometimes that may cause this type of errors. In your code there can be other issues also, since you are not returning, optional there is a chance of NullPointerException as you are not checking the returned link is null or not.

Comment: Also, please check your import is this ```import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;```

Comment: Still not working. I tried to use '@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "subLinks")' and I checked if link is null. It is not null. (Link exists)... The import is right too. Thank you for your time...!

Comment: @tqnone how did you check if `@Transactional` is not working?

Comment: I get the LazyInitializationException. If @Transactional would work as expected I would not get the LazyInitializationException. Am I right? By the way: I added TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() to the service method findById() and as result I get 'true'.

Comment: @tqnone not right, *transactionality* and *lazy initialization* are two different things.

Comment: Hibernate documentation says *org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException:* Indicates access to unfetched data outside of a session context. AND `@Transactional`, meaning that any failure causes the entire operation to roll back to its previous state and to re-throw the original exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Aman** explained well the cause of the `LazyInitializationException` in your case and **crizzis** added more information about why `@Transactional` is not worked as you expected and how it should be used.

So, to summarize the options you have to solve your problem:

---

### Fetch Eager

Commented by **Aman** and **crizzis**, this is the easier but not the best from the point of view of the performance.

To do it, include `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` in `subLinks` property definition:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "link", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Collection<SubLink> subLinks;
```

However, every time you get from database instances of `Link` => its collection of related `SubLink` will be included.

---

### Custom Query

Commented by **Aman** too (although is not necessary `on (link.id = sublink.link.id)`). In this case, you can create a new method in your repository to get the `SubLink` collection of an specific `Link`.

In this way, you will be able to deal with situations on which you want to receive such "extra information" (`findWithSubLinkById`) or not (provided `findById`).

With a **bidirectional `OneToMany`**, it is enough with something like:

```
@Query("select l from Link l left join fetch l.subLinks where l.id = :id")
Link findWithSubLinkById(Long id);
```

With a **unidirectional `OneToMany`**, besides the above query you have to include how "join" both tables:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "link_id")
private Collection<SubLink> subLinks;
```

Removing `link` property from `SubLink` class.

More information in [Hibernate associations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations) and [unidirectional one-to-many tips](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-unidirectional-one-to-many-association-without-junction-table/)

---

### EntityGraph

This is a variation of the previous one. So, instead of create the new method using `@Query`, an easier choice will be configured with `@EntityGraph`:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = "subLinks")
Link findWithSubLinkById(Long id);
```

More information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph) (`Example 77`)

---

### Work inside Transactional method

As **crizzis** commented, inside the method configured with `@Transactional` you won't receive such exception. So, another option is move the code that uses `Sublink` from your controller to your service.

Answer (score 1):

`LazyInitializationException` indicates access to unfetched data outside of a session context. To fix this, you have to fetch all required associations within your service layer.

I think in your case you are fetching `Link` without its `SubLink`, but trying to access sublinks. So, using *JOIN FETCH* would be the best strategy.

**Note:** You can use `FetchType.EAGER` too, but it might affect performance. Because, it will always fetch fetch the association, even if you don’t use them.

**= UPDATE =**

Thanks to **crizzi** for mentioning an interesting feature called **Open Session In View(OSIV)** (enabled by default in spring-boot applications). Though it depends on who you may ask to label it as a *pattern* or an *antipattern*.

The main purpose is to to facilitate working with lazy associations(avoids `LazyInitializationException`). Very detailed explanation can be found on

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view and
- https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. In fact, to fix this I am using JOIN but I would like to know why '@Transactional' is not working. '@Transactional' should do similar stuff, or am I wrong?

Comment: A transaction is a sequence of operations considered as single unit of work. For instance, within a transaction you can fetch and then update an entity. If one of the operations fails, it is considered as both have failed.

Comment: @tqnone you said you are using *JOIN*. is it *JOIN* or *JOIN FETCH*?

Comment: This one: @Query("SELECT link FROM Link link LEFT JOIN FETCH link.subLinks WHERE link.id = ?1"). Should not be '@Transactional' without @Query(...) enough?

Comment: What is `link.subLinks`?

Comment: Aman, the problem is not the query. This query works. The solution is okay. But I would like to know  why the second solution with '@Transacitonal' is not working.

Comment: Aman my query works good. The problem is that '@Transactional' is not working in my example. In this example there is no '@Query' (thats another solution)

Comment: Look that is what I understand: The first solution is about to use '@Transactional' only. The second solution is about to use '@Query' with JOIN FETCH. I would like to know WHY the first solution is not working, that is why I am asking. I am not talking about the second solution. Of course I am thankful for your help!

Comment: @tqnone If you are not using a query, you can use `FetchType. EAGER`

Comment: @tqnone  `@Transactional` is like a container for your calls to database. A transaction should be ACID, rigth? That's all it is doing. It doesn't matter which ever query you issued. It only protects you from writing/reading **inconsistent** data.

Comment: @tqnone You put `@Transactional` on top of `findById`, which means a persistence context is open **for the execution of `findById`** and a transaction gets created **for the execution of `findById`**. Now, if you called `link.getSublinks()` from **inside** `findById`, there would be no error. However, your code is calling `link.getSublinks()` **outside of `findById`**, where the persistence context is already closed. I hope that clears things up

Comment: The problem is, to-many associations are lazily fetched by default, meaning they are loaded from the data store at first access. If that access happens inside a transaction, where the persistence context is still open, everything's fine. If, on the other hand, the first access happens outside of a transaction - too bad, the data can no longer be fetched at that point. You need to use `fetch = EAGER` to make sure the collection is fetched with the transaction still open (recommended) or enable out-of-transaction fetching by `spring.jpa.open-in-view: true` (not recommended)

Comment: @crizzis thank you for wrapping things up. However, isn't *OSIV* enabled by default in springMVC too? Though there is nothing mentioning it in the question?

Comment: Depends on the version of Spring Boot, if I remember rightly. And the reason why it is not a good practice is, since you're getting part of the entity state outside of the transaction, the result might be in an inconsistent state

Comment: Thank you very very very much guys. I got it! :-) @[crizzis, Aman, doctore]

Comment: @tqnone glad to hear that